# Can I enable Vim in editing pane only in PyCharm (i.e. disable Vim in Console)?

Tags: python, pycharm, ideavim

I enable IdeaVim in my PyCharm, and the vim mode works in the editing pane. However, this also makes Vim effective in Console, which is the side-effect I don't need at all.

Can I disable Vim mode in Console but still have it work in editing pane? Any hacks that are hidden from the standard preference pane might be welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the Vim emulation for the console?

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh I want it more like I use REPL in Terminal.

Comment: Got it, but what exactly is bothering you?

Comment: For me, the problem is that I can't interact with the` help(...)` command in the REPL. eg `help(int)`. Pycharm says to I can kill the current window by using `Ctrl+C` but that just puts me into a vim edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to switch off the Vim emulation only in console windows.

For problems with `<Esc>` and possible workarounds follow [VIM-740](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-740).